# Screen order issues using usb 3.0 to hdmi

Tags: windows-10, usb

### ***Introduction***

I really need your help, and I hope to post pictures and everything possible at another time to help you understand my problem.

Firstly, I have a system that plays video on several screens simultaneously, so if I buy a pc and put, for example, two simple offboard video cards that have hdmi and dvi outputs, I can put two hdmi monitors, and show my contents on those screens, and Of course, to keep order, I always log into Windows.

I save a profile of the monitors through my system with the help of the multimonitor tools, an excellent tool.

### **Let's go to the problem**

But I recently discovered technology from Silicon Motorn, a chipset manufacturer, a USB 3.0 device for dual hdmi, enter on usb 3.0 and gives you 2 hdmi outputs to add tvs or monitors, so it is fantastic, however when using 2 of these devices windows cannot save the order of the monitors, if i leave ordered 1234 in windows and restart the pc it may or may not change the order because the usb are connected and have a different time or something that makes them go up and do not save the order that I left, different from conventional video cards if that happens, you can load the previous order through applications that we know play the role of saving the order, but in the case of these wavlink usb 3.0 to hdmi devices, it is not possible to rewind the order when windows restarts or shuts down, so to do this you have to go to the device manager and disable these adapters and then yes they come back, so what I did was get the devcon or usbdeview and create a bat to disable and enable it, but this is not 100% safe I would need to understand how I can do it that they go up exactly as I want, and don't lose my order in windows or any software that can get their order back, remembering that no software worked in this case, displayfusion, duramon, multimonitor, as it is different from a video card.

Does anyone have any idea how to preserve the order of the monitors in windows even when turning off or turning on the computer?

Wonder if a usb 3.0 hub would be able to restart these devices by making them start at the same time? and so would not lose the order previously saved in windows?
Thanks guys if you need I can demonstrate the problem even more.

[Used material:](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0943VNT67)
USB 3.0 to hdmi

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not willing to even read this ball 'o text.  Paragraphs are your friend.  Please [take the tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and read [how to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).  People here are happy to help you but not like this.

Comment: Welcome to SU. There's a lot of text, but it's _really_ hard to make head or tails sense of. Maybe you could [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1773138/edit) it a little, try to focus it and leave out unnecessities like "Big hug to all". It's also a good idea to write shorter sentences separated by `.` and use paragraphs to separate the text. The [Help](https://superuser.com/help) has good guidelines on [how to formulate a clear question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) that can also be answered. You can upload screenshots to imgur and add the links - someone will put the images in.

Comment: Instead of using a separate multi-monitor tool, did you try the built in tool?  Right click on the Desktop and goto **Display Settings**.  There you should be able to drag and drop the monitors into the correct order, and click apply.

Comment: @cybernard Hi cybernard, it's not that simple, when I wrote this post I was already trying this and other ways to fix the positions, if you read the post above again you will see that I have a usb to hdmi 3.0 from wavlink, so I don't have any cards video, and that's where things change a little, when you have tools like display fusion, multimonitor or other tools that preserve the monitor profile. In tests I have two adapters and this only happens when you have two or more of these devices connected. It's as if the time Windows takes to load them can interfere with the order they start.